# How does Worldbuilding work?

Tags: support

Sorry if this question is a little stupid, but how does this worldbuilding page work? Are people building their own worlds or are you just talking about questions that you find interesting to talk about?

If people are building their own worlds, what are they doing with them? Are they talking about them in a blog or something?

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding! If you have questions about how this site works please [take the tour](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour) and [visit the help center](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help). There is a lot of useful information there. Generally we try to help authors create logically consistent worlds. For example: how to design a creature with specific traits? How to design a certain weapon? How big has my planet to be? And there are many more things.

Comment: If you got questions about this site you can ping someone with @Username. This question will probably get "put on hold" at first, as it does not fit the [sites guidelines](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Normally a question can be reopened if it is put on hold and was edited by the author. This is a standard procedure around here if there a problems with questions so that no answers are invalidated by edits. In this case the question will probably get closed and deleted after some time as it is no normal question. Looking forward to your first WorldBuilding Q! Have fun!

Comment: Your question has been moved to meta. This is a part of worldbuilding used to discuss issues about the site so that the sites homepage remains as just worldbuilding questions. If you have a question for the site but aren't sure if it's right you can post it in the [sandbox](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/635/sandbox-for-proposed-questions)  and get some feedback.

Answer (score 6):

Youstay is correct... but also too limited.

People build world's for hundreds of reasons. Some run role playing games.  Some are writers for books or short stories or comics.  Some are creating computer games or even TV shows.

Anytime that you are creating an imaginary world for any reason world building is here for you...

Comment: Even if someone isn't building a world, [we're still here for them](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/3326/6986).

Answer (score 3):

To address your question of *...what are they doing with them?*:

There's people that just enjoy to *create*. Some are building a boat in their garage for 4 decades, others have their [model railway](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modelleisenbahn) hidden in the attic/basement where they spend weeks building a little pond, others again go big and design a whole world because they might like to philosophize in a more practical way & manner about large scale things such as population shifts and what-not.

While, as already mentioned, there's some people that publish their work and make money with it - there's plenty of work that will never touch the mind of anyone outside a small circle of friends.

---

For me it's a combination of both. I enjoy digging into theoretical problems and use the world I build as a framework for these questions while exploring them.

I also eventually would like to publish my world in the form of a novel or probably rather some interactive fiction - but that's way off for now :)

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to worldbuilding SE.

This site is specifically about the details of how to build your virtual world. It is aimed at helping writers and animators (people who create computer animations) in building the details of their worlds. You could discuss any aspect of your world (magic, physics, creature design etc) and members with the relevant information would help you fill in the details.

Also, if you have questions about the functionality of this site, then you should post those questions on [The Meta Section](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/).

We look forward to your very productive stay at this place :)

Comment: Just my opinion but either you or Secespitus should indicate there is a SandBox area for would be questioners to pretest or run by people to see if a question meets the requirements and if not how to bring it into specs.