# Can I ask about mythological creatures here?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I wanted to ask if I can ask about mythological creatures. For example, I wanted to ask about a succubus (What are its physiological details, types, etc.).

Comment: this link is the right place: https://mythology.stackexchange.com/ This place would be ideal if your thinking to create a succubus in your current world or create properties for it.

Comment: This question belongs on meta, but the short answer is yes, check out the [tag:creature-design]

Comment: You should have a look at [Anatomically Correct Creatures](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/anatomically-correct-series)

Comment: Do check out our [question sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4835/29).

Answer (score 14):

Now that this is on Meta, I feel ok answering it.

## *Absolutely*

We've got a [whole bunch](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=anatomically+correct) of "anatomically correct..." questions, along with several questions that branch off into related topics once that question gets answered. Not to mention a [mythical-creatures](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mythical-creatures) tag.

Some examples:

[Anatomically Correct Pegasus](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/55996/anatomically-correct-pegasus) (asked just the other day)

[Would swimming dragons need wings?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/81664/would-swimming-dragons-need-wings) (about a week old)

[What would a Mermaid’s taste buds be like?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/80855/what-would-a-mermaid-s-taste-buds-be-like)

[If mountain lions were Griffins, how would it affect other animals?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/35095/if-mountain-lions-were-griffins-how-would-it-affect-other-animals?s=4|0.4697)

[Does a world with domestic flying creatures (eg: dragons) needs cars, planes and ships?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/81901/does-a-world-with-domestic-flying-creatures-eg-dragons-needs-cars-planes-and?s=1|0.5911)

Take a look-see to see what's already been asked and if you have a new question, just make sure it falls within what's considered "on topic" and avoid being too broad. Old questions will help.

Comment: Thanks for waiting to answer.

Answer (score 12):

We help people to build *consistent*, *fictional* worlds for novels, games, etc. A question like "what is a succubus" would be off topic, a question like "here is the succubus for my setting, are there unintended side effects from the game mechanics" would be on topic.